# how to speed up the tcpip communication between client and server?

Tags: performance, tcp, fork

1. c program
2. client thread 10
3. server listen(serverFD, 10)
4. tcp/ip
5. client make 4.5k bytes message and send to server
6. if server connect to client and fork() is running and processing

Threre are my programs as follows:

1. client main.java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3cb2.png)
original program
2. server c programs
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jwDr.png)
original program : MAX_CLIENTS = 10

3. I change the number as

- listen parameter 10 to 100, 500 and
  in java main
  *ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);*
  -> *ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1000);*

has no change of speed

Comment: You should not expect any change of speed between 10 clients in a single host and a server over a single network. The backlog parameter has nothing to do with it.